# How to use ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does this return statement works?

```
return [weekend, !weekend ? 'myweekend' : ''];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `weekend` is false/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will return `[weekend, 'myweekend']` otherwise `[weekend, '']`